# Using FindControl() to get HtmlTextArea with kendo editor from html table

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, kendo-ui, textarea

So unless I'm absolutely crazy I did get this to work, then for some reason it stopped and I couldn't get back to the working version. Basically I can't directly access the `HtmlTextArea` by setting `runat="server"` because that breaks the *Kendo editor*, so I'm trying to use `FindControl` on the *html data cell* above it to get it; however, this is returning null and I don't know how to fix it.

aspx code:

```
<td id="cellBody" runat="server" class="auto-style7" ColSpan="3">
    <textarea id="txtBody" rows="10" style="width:450px; height:100px"></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#txtBody").kendoEditor();
        }); 
     </script>
</td>
```

C# code:

```
((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea)cellBody.FindControl("txtBody")).Value = string.Empty;
```

The `FindControl("txtBody")` call returns *null*. If I look at the `.Controls` property on the cell though it does contain the literal text for the *txtBody*, I just can't seem to get the actual object.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Alright, so this has been a long, somewhat embarassing, road, but I figured it out. I feel like this is just a newbie mistake, but maybe it will help someone. Turns out you can use runat="server" on the textarea, you just have to reference it like '#<%= txtBody.ClientID %>' in the js code. The best part is I tried this before, I just left out the '#'. Lessons in humility I guess. xP

Comment: So maybe someone can help me with this instead: now that it works the editor has this weird habit of converting the text it contains into html format whenever I pull it's value. I.E. I pull the value to display in html in a file, but then the actual text in the editor become html code such that the next value pulled is double encoded. I'm thinking this might be because I'm pulling from the HtmlTextArea not the kendo editor, but I don't know if I can access the editor itself. Ideas?

Comment: Ok I lied, it's when the page is re-loaded, not when I get a the value.

Comment: Alright, kinda feel silly asking and answering my questions repeatedly, but on the off chance some newbie like me has this question again all I had to do was pass in {encoded: false} to the kendoEditor function in the js script.